# Fetching HTML from a GAE application using GAS (custom function for spreadsheets)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I have built a very useful database and set of tools on Google App Engine. I have begun a new job, related to my old job, and I want to access some of the data from my GAE application.

Long story short, this code in Google App Script fails when used with Google Apps Spreadsheet:

```
function getData(id) {
    url = "http://fakeapp.appspot.com/functions/func?id=" + id;
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        return response.getContentText();
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

In the spread sheet you'd have:

`=getDate("XYZ")`

Which ought to return some value:

`10000`

In my GAE yaml file, there is no authorization required for this specific url. However, when you use this custom function in Google Spreadsheets, it basically pulls the html from the very familiar Google login page:

> One account. All of Google.

That sort of thing. Questions:

- (1) Am I trying to do something which is impossible? I have the fetch working in many other scenarios so it appears to be specific with my GAE app.
- (2) If not, how do I get this working?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try doing an ajax get from a regular webapp (client js). if you also get the authentication there, its easier to debug. also try https

Comment: Thanks, well it looks like one issue is I must use HTTPS. Thanks. But I am not not being allowed access, here is the output: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://fakeapp.appspot.com/functions/func?id=XYZ. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://docs.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html also s.o. has answers to that one.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that before you sent it. I am mystified. I have implemented the header, tested them to make sure they are there (e,g used http://web-sniffer.net/ to test) but I am STILL getting the exact same error. I'll have to play with it some more.

Comment: The Access-Control-Origin issue shouldn't be present in Apps Script, it runs server side, that's a client-side javascript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely access your App Engine application from apps script with UrlFetchApp, I use that approach regularly.

If you are getting the Google login page the endpoint on GAE must be requiring some authentication.

UrlFetchApp requests from Apps Script are anonymous requests, they don't pass along the credentials of the user executing the script.